# Plugin which was built using Eclipse-rcp Neon not working on Eclipse Photon

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-photon

I am trying to run the Eclipse plugin which was built using Neon release on the latest versions of Eclipse. So far it works fine on the Oxygen release but doesn't work on the other latest releases.

I have the source code of the plugin (on Neon-rcp) from which I created the plugin's jar file and installed it on Neon and Oxygen versions and it works fine but when I install it on Photon, 2018-09 and 2018-12 and launch the Eclipse IDE it gives me an error message to read the log file. In the log file it states that an error occurred while activating the bundle. I even installed the java 1.8.0_102 in which the plugin was built. I searched for solutions but couldn't find one which could solve this issue. Please see the log below.

[log from Photon](https://pastebin.com/Wws7TPrG)

```
do{
   PleaseIgnore();
  } while(true);
```

I have no clue how to solve this problem as it works fine on Neon and Oxygen release. My main goal is to run it on the other latest releases.
It would be a great help if someone point me in the right direction to solve this issue.

Thanks.

P.S : I don't have much experience with java and eclipse.

Comment: All the errors log `The instance data location has not been specified yet` - looks like something is probably trying to activate the ResourcesPlugin too early in the startup. Does the plugin use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point or something like that?

Comment: What is org.apache.felix doing in this application?

Comment: @nitind org.apache.felix.scr is included as part of core Eclipse in the most recent versions. It replaces org.eclipse.equinox.ds

Comment: @greg-449 the extension points tab seems to be empty but there are so many extensions in the Extension tab.

Comment: 'Extension Points' is for extension points that the plug-in creates and will often be empty. 'Extensions' are the extension points from other plug-ins that the plug-in uses and will often contain many entries.

Comment: ok, there is no org.eclipse.ui.startup in the 'Extentions' but there are others like 'org.eclipse.ui.views' , 'org.eclipse.ui.menus' , 'commands' ... etc

Comment: @greg-449 here is the list of all extension points [link](https://ibb.co/cw3XB2n) and [link](https://ibb.co/B2Yhr6X)

Comment: Sorry but this is not something that can be solved with a StackOverflow question. It needs a detailed look at the plug-in and probably a good deal of debugging.